# C# linq query- How to query on inner table with list of values

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I am working on C# EntityFramework linq query. I am having trouble how to write the following scenario.
I have Person table and alias table and have foreign Key relationship between tables. If User search by "firstname lastname" or "lastname firstname" need to give the results if it present in persontable otherwise need look into alias table get the result. In database , the fullname is following format "lastname firstname" or "firstname lastname".

```
Person Table: (Id, Fullname)        Alias Table:(Id PersonId Fullname)
```

1. I am splitting the name search by user using spaces and stores those strings in array.
2. I am able to successfully get the results from the Person table. I am having trouble getting the results from alias table.
3. Following is the query I am working:

.

```
string[] lsNames = val.Split(' ', ',', '&');
var a = this.context.Person
   .Include(x => x.Alias)
   .Where(x => x.Alias.Any(v => 
       lsNames.All(n=>v.Name.ToLower().Contains(n.ToLower()))));
```

I need to return the person table and including the aliases. How to search list of values in the alias table using linq query.

The above query is giving me the error- evaluation time out. Could anyone please help me solving this problem.

Comment: x.Alias - it is one-to-many relationship?

Answer (score 3):

If your application is enforcing that the stored full name is "{first} {last}" and-or "{last} {first}" and the issue is that you want to compare a user entry which could be any reasonable user format, then I'd consider parsing the input string, deciding on whether it's particularly valid, and then issuing specific conditions based on that.

For instance, if the data is stored as "{first} {last}":

```
if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(name))
    return null; // or handle no name search provided.

var nameParts = name.Split(new [] {' ', ',', '&'}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

var query = Context.Person.AsQueryable();

if (nameParts.Length == 1)
    query = query.Where(x => x.Fullname.Contains(nameParts[0]));
else if (nameParts.Length == 2)
{
    var combination1 = string.Join(" ", nameParts);
    Array.Reverse(nameParts);
    var combination2 = string.Join(" ", nameParts);

    query = query.Where(x => x.Fullname == combination1 || x.Fullname == combination2 );
}
else
{ // More than 2 name components, so assume they are typing 
  // "{first} {middle} {last}" or "{last}, {first} {middle}"

    var combination1 = string.Join(" ", nameParts);
    // Shift the first element (last name) to the end 
    var firstElement = nameParts[0];
    Array.Copy(nameParts, 1, nameParts, 0, nameParts.Length- 1);
    nameParts[nameParts.Length - 1] = firstElement;        
    var combination2 = string.Join(" ", nameParts);

    query = query.Where(x => x.Fullname == combination1 || x.Fullname == combination2); 

}

var people = query.ToList();
```

This imposes set limits on how the input string will be searched. This assumes the database comparison by EF will be case insensitive, as per SQL Server /w most default correlations. If the database comparisons are case sensitive then hopefully the data is always stored with a consistent case (always upper or always lower) then the appropriate case can be applied above. Ideally just to the string fed into the expression, not both the evaluation string and the entity/db column. (More work for the DB)

The above scenario limits the checks that if a user types in a single word like "Peter" it will find "Peter Smith", or "Mitch Peterson"  Where if they typed "Peter Smith" or "Smith, Peter" that would match on "Peter Smith" but not "Peter Smithe" for instance. Having a looser comparison across combinations will result in a lot more work for SQL to ultimately need to process.  Introducing rules/expectations for input and validating those will result in more code, but simpler/faster queries.  The risk of `Contains`-like querying is that this leaves the possibility that users can cripple your queries with strings like "I am an evil b or c or d or e" Imagine the OR'd like conditions that `Contains` combined with `Any`/'All` would produce for the combinations in that resulting array. It's generally safer to be more pessimistic with user input and let users refine their entry than trying to accommodate near matches, especially without dealing with specific columns like .FirstName and .LastName.

Comment: Thanks @Stev Py for the clear idea. I worked on based on your suggestion. It worked for few scenarios. but we need to configure some rules on the frontend side. Thank you so much for giving explanation.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use helper which can build the following predicate:

```
Expression<Func<Alias, boo>> aliasPredicate = a => 
   a.Name.ToLower().Contains(lsNames[0]) ||
   a.Name.ToLower().Contains(lsNames[1]) ...
);
```

For example using [LINQKit](https://github.com/scottksmith95/LINQKit)

```
string[] lsNames = val.ToLower().Split(' ', ',', '&');

var builder = PredicateBuilder.New<Alias>();
foreach (var n in lsNames)
{
   var name = n; // avoid closure capturing of n variable
   builder = builder.Or(a => a.Name.ToLower().Contains(name));
}

var personQuery = this.context.Person
  .Where(x => x.Alias.AsQueryable().Any(builder));
```

Note, it will retrieve only persons but not their aliases.
`Include(x => x.Alias)` may slowdown query. For better performance we have to create more complex solution with client side post processing.

Proposed solution is almost the best when using standard `IQueryable` extensions and EF Core. Note, there are also database specific features like Full Text Search, which can improve query significally.

Answer (score 0):

If you are getting timeout errors, you need to check your indexing to make sure Name is indexed and that the index is being used correctly. For example, if your column is set as varchar not nvarchar, SQL will do a type coersion in the where clause and may ignore your index as a result. You can force EF to not use unicode if necessary, but the syntax varies depending on which version of EF you are using and how you are configuring your mappings.

Also, as @Steve Py mentioned, you don't need to do ToLower on your strings because most SQL queries are case insensitive.

Answer (score 0):

If you are splitting the name into parts and want to search for a match on the parts then you are joining collections and when I'm joining collections and I can't use navigation properties I usually opt for query syntax:

```
var query = from person in this.context.Person
from name in lsNames
where person.Name.StartsWith(name) || person.Aliases.Any(a => a.Name.StartsWith(name))
select person;

return query.ToList()
```

This may not be the most efficient search because it is using wildcards and you may want an exact match.

If you are doing that then you could use StevePy's technique to populate the lsNames array and use a similar query:

```
string[] lsNames = {combination1, combination2)

var query = from person in this.context.Person
from name in lsNames
where person.Name == name || person.Aliases.Any(a => a.Name == name)
select person;

return query.ToList()
```